# "Two grades senior/junior to me"

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-usage, expressions

Let's say I'm in the fourth grade and my brother is in the sixth. Is it legitimate to say,

> He is two grades senior to me?

I googled the phrase ***two grades senior to me*** and there were only 10 results, so I thought that's probably not a natural way of putting it but I couldn't figure out how to say what I wanted to say either.

Comment: If you’re talking about school, I would probably use “two grades ahead” in American English. It might be different in British English. Example *“I watched him grow up a little bit,” said Hayes, who was two grades ahead of Teter at Lake Gibson.* (https://virginiasports.com/news/2021/07/15/hayes-brings-championship-pedigree-to-secondary/)

Comment: Native English (Am) speakers would say as @ColleenV pointed out, or just say, "He is in the sixth grade. I'm in the fourth."

Comment: I agree with ColleenV, or maybe just ["two grades older"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22two+grades+older%22).

Comment: Thanks a lot, everyone. **_Two grades ahead_** looks fine to me. But how about someone who is my junior? Will he be **_two grades behind me_**? Or do I have to just say what @FeliniusRex suggested?

Comment: I'm British, I'd say "He's two grades above/below me" (although I'd actually say "years" not "grades").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's legitimate to say, *"He's two grades senior to me."* It's not idiomatic English though, and sounds old-fashioned. "*He's two grades **my senior***" is more idiomatic, but still old-fashioned.

Natural English of today would be

> "*He's two grades **ahead of me***" or
>
> "*He's two grades **above me.***"

For the reverse situation, the counterpart to "senior" is "junior", so

> "*He's two grades **my junior***" (old-fashioned, but idiomatic),
>
> "*He's two grades **behind me***" or
>
> "*He's two grades **below me***"